# Wireless hotspot with firewall settings

Tags: windows-10, windows-firewall, wireless-hotspot

In a smaller company where I work I would like to create WIFI network that would exclude access to our local network (network printer, network drives etc.)

I have one older laptop with Windows 10 that has a with broken keyboard, so I would like to use the laptop for this purpose. My idea is to create classic permanent hotspot in Windows settings and then block all the local IP addresses in Windows firewall** (192.*.*.* and 10.*.*.*).

Is this possible? Are there any alternatives that might work equally as well?

*(I don't want to buy any special router if it's possible to use just the broken laptop for this.)*

Comment: Technically possible, but it is going to do a poor job as a router and the energy saving of a proper router will soon cover the minimal purchase cost.

Comment: @tetech classic router doesn't have firewall with such possibilities

Comment: You need a VLAN router so that you can get up Normal and Guest LAN segments that are isolated from each other. I think trying to do this in the router firewall may not be practical.

Comment: In other words, I need to spend a lot of money for new hardware you are saying.